# Button Click Not Recognized on Canvas

Tags: wpf, events, button, canvas

Hi I have the following code, I am drawing a button on a canvas with a button template, when I click on the button I want a message to show up, but it doesn't, even when I register a mouse down event on the button it is still not recognized.

```
 private void Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {

         Button r = e.Source as Button;
         if (r != null)
            MessageBox.Show(r.ToString());

        Point mousePoint = Mouse.GetPosition(mainCanvas);
        Button button1 = new Button();


        button1.Template = (ControlTemplate)this.FindResource("nodeTemplate");
        Canvas.SetTop(button1, mousePoint.Y);
        Canvas.SetLeft(button1, mousePoint.X);
        mainCanvas.Children.Add(button1);


    }
}
```

---

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="nodeTemplate" TargetType="Button">
        <Grid>
            <Ellipse x:Name="outerCircle" Fill="Red" Height="50" Width="50"/>
            <Ellipse x:Name="innerCircle" Fill="Green" RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5">
                <Ellipse.RenderTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX=".9" ScaleY=".9"/>
                </Ellipse.RenderTransform>    
            </Ellipse> 
        </Grid>            

    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>

<DockPanel>
    <Canvas x:Name="mainCanvas" Background="Transparent" MouseLeftButtonDown="Canvas_MouseLeftButtonDown">

    </Canvas>
</DockPanel>
```

Comment: @Meleak : I think I deleted Meleak's answer by mistake, could you repost.

Comment: Hehe no, it was me who deleted it. I figured this was the common Background is null problem but after looking at your code more closely I noticed you already had `Background="Transparent"` so the answer was useless :)

Comment: @Meleak :Background is transparent for the canvas though, the button has a Fill and no background property, do you know what the difference is between Background and Fill.

But Ellipse doesn't have a Background property.

Comment: Fill is defined on Shape so every control which inherits from `Shape` has a `Fill` property. Shapes usually don't have a `Foreground` property so it isn't really a `Background` since nothing will be drawn on top of it by the shape itself, it just fills :) `Background` is defined on `Control` and `TextElement` (and maybe somewhere else as well)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `MouseLeftButtonDown` is marked as handled by the Button, the event will not reach the canvas, use `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` instead (as they use different [routing strategies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies) this event cannot be intercepted by the Button because it is raised on the Canvas first). Alternatively you can attach the event `ButtonBase.Click` to the Canvas, this of course only registers Button-clicks.

Comment: the event handler is on the canvas if you look in the xaml, i have to run now but I will try the buttonbase.click later.

Comment: @mihajlv: I know it is on the canvas, and the event is [bubbling](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx#routing_strategies), but as soon as `e.Handled` is set to `true` when it passes through the button it will no longer reach the canvas. `PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown` on the other hand is tunneling, i.e. the event is first raised on the canvas, and then travels to the button, thus it cannot be intercepted.

Comment: i see, i put the same MouseLeftButtonDown event handler on the button too, but it still doesn't catch the event, do you know why this is so? from what you said above i think the button should catch it first and handle it.
-----------------------------
    `void button1_MouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("clicked");
        }
`

Comment: @mihajlv: You should not put any event on the button, use the **`Preview`**`MouseLeftButtonDown` on the canvas, i tested it and it works as expected.

Comment: i understand what you saying but am a little confused about how it works as explained in the comment above. since this event is bubbling up shouldn't the button be able intercept it fist and handle it? I understand that it will work with the tunneling approach since the canvas will intercept it first.

Comment: @mihajlv: I was talking about different events, read more closely. And read the [Routed Events Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742806.aspx) i already linked to twice.

Comment: :apologies, i see what you are saying, however, i wanted to try to see if I can intercept the MouseLeftButtonDown with the button, but it doesn't work, do you know why?

Comment: the button in the canvas is catching the click event, but not the MouseLeftButtonDown even though there are handlers for both and both are bubbling events...

Comment: @mihajlv: You can never get that event to work with a button, the event is handled internally so even when you try to handle it on the button itself the event will not fire.